# How to parse specific data from JSON file to a html dropdown menu

Tags: java, html, css, json

[JSON FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMbsk.png)

Hi, in the json file i have shown above there is over 30 matchdays and i was wondering how would i be able to parse the data  from the JSON file to a html file and have the options in a dropdown menu to be able to filter by matchdays or filter by teams, is it possible to do this or am I overthinking it, i have the file parsing the data and showing all results from the json file into a table as shown below 
[html file showing all matchdays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4KKv.png)

i was wondering is there a way i can filter these results by specific team or matchdays ? any help appreciated thanks

[html file taking in the json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVMBN.png)

Comment: Hi, is JSON file will be uploaded from HTML or HTML gets JSON response from server side?

Comment: the html parses the json file using a xmlhttp request

Comment: i have edited the question to show how the html takes the json in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code snippet would help you to finish your work.

```
var json = '{"name":"EnglishPremierLeague2015","rounds":[{"name":"Matchday1:","matches":[{"date":"2015-08-08","team1":{"key":"manutd","name":"ManchesterUnite","code":"MUN"},"team2":{"key":"tottenham","name":"TottenhamHotspu","code":"TOT"},"scorer":1,"score2":0}]},{"name":"Matchday2:","matches":[{"date":"2015-08-09","team1":{"key":"India","name":"IndianCricketTeam","code":"IND"},"team2":{"key":"England","name":"EnglandCricketTeam","code":"ENG"},"scorer":1,"score2":0}]}]}';

var data = JSON.parse(json);

// Filter by Match Day
var filter = $(data.rounds).filter(function () { 
    return this.name == "Matchday1:";
})

// Test Case :)
if (filter.length == 1) {
    console.log("Filter working")
}

var filterbyTeam = $(data.rounds).filter(function () {
    return this.matches.filter(function (e) {
        return e.team1.key == "India" || e.team2.key == "India";
    }).length >= 1;
})

// Test Case :)
if (filterbyTeam.length == 1) {
    console.log("Filter working")
}
```

This code will get the JSON array with the filter that you can use further to show your HTML.

Note: You need to pass filter text according to your requirement. You can change the attribute as well to filter specific data.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: what would be the simplest way to add to filter to select which match day you would like to view ?, im sorry but im really new to this and finding it extremely difficult